# Python Dataframe: Remove digits in odd position from df rows?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a df with two columns `number` ,`type`. I'm trying to remove the number in odd position if `type` is `odd`.

For number - `(7,14,21,28)` without numbers in `odd` position - `7,21`.

Similarly - `(3,10,17,24,31)` without numbers in `odd` position - `3,17,31`

df

```
    df= pd.DataFrame(data = {'number' : ['7,14,21,28', '2', '3,6,5,8 ', '4', '3,10,17,24,31'], 'day' : ['odd', 'even', 'even', 'even', 'odd']}) 


    number          type
0   7,14,21,28      odd
1   2               even   
2   3,6,5,8         even
3   4               even
4   3,10,17,24,31   odd
```

My excepted output:

```
        number          type
    0   7,21            odd
    1   2               even   
    2   3,6,5,8         even
    3   4               even
    4   3,17,31         odd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple [`string slicing`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-slicing-in-python/) with `step = 2`:

```
In [1755]: df.number = np.where(df['day'].eq('odd'), df.number.str.split(',').str[::2].str.join(','), df['number'])

In [1759]: df                                              
Out[1759]: 
     number   day
0      7,21   odd
1         2   even
2   3,6,5,8   even
3         4   even
4   3,17,31   odd
```

Comment: `np.where(df['day'].eq('odd'), df.number.str.split(',').str[::2].str.join(','), df['number'])` one line

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
df.loc[df['day'] == "odd", "number"] = df.loc[df['day'] == "odd", "number"]. \
    apply(lambda x : ",".join([str(i) for i in x.split(",") if int(i) % 2 != 0]))
```

---

```
     number   day
0      7,21   odd
1         2  even
2  3,6,5,8   even
3         4  even
4   3,17,31   odd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) functionality to compute the calculation for each row.

```py
d = pd.DataFrame(
      data = {'number' : ['7,14,21,28', '2', '3,6,5,8 ', '4', '3,10,17,24,31'],       
      'type' : ['odd', 'even', 'even', 'even', 'odd']})

d['number'] = d.apply(
   lambda row: \
      ", ".join(row['number'].split(',')[::2]) 
      if row['type'] == 'odd' 
      else row['number'], axis=1)

print(d.to_string())

      number  type
0      7, 21   odd
1          2  even
2   3,6,5,8   even
3          4  even
4  3, 17, 31   odd
```